# Python keyring directly showing password without prompting master password

Tags: python-keyring

import keyring
keyring.set_password('test_db','louis','secret123')
keyring.get_password('test_db','louis')
'secret123'

> > > 

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **keyring.cryptfile**.
With this way, a cryptfile_pass.cfg file will created with hashed passwords (argon2 hash).

You can use it like this:

```
from keyrings.cryptfile.cryptfile import CryptFileKeyring

kr = CryptFileKeyring()
kr.set_password("service", "username", "my_secret_key_code")
>>>Type your password: MyPass_word

kr.get_password("service", "username")
>>>Please enter password for encrypted keyring:
```

if you press:'my_secret_key_code' you will get:
MyPass_word

See more [here](https://pypi.org/project/keyrings.cryptfile/).